# ARC and Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, automatic-ref-counting

I have an interesting question about interface builder and ARC. I am building a view controller that will be initialized with a xib. I use the tap-and-drag capability of interface builder to create necessary property outlets for my xib. This initalizes the property as (weak, nonatomic). Sounds fine to me.

What's throwing me off is that lines such as `[self setCategoryButton:nil];` are automatically added to viewDidUnload. I understand and used this before ARC. However, since these are weak references, wouldn't they automatically be cleared when the view unloads?

I suppose I could see the value in nil-ing these properties if those views are retained by other objects, but that seems an unusual case to me... Just wanted to get further feedback on the point.

Thanks,

Kurt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I filed a bug on this a while back, and the response that I got was that this is intentional behavior. Since Xcode cannot verify that there are no other strong references to the view, it cannot actually *guarantee* that the weak pointer would be automatically cleared in `-viewDidUnload`. Thus, they clear it for you.

Personally, I think this is a lame reason, but that's the reason that was given.

Answer (score 3):

It will only be set to nil in iOS5 or later (iOS 4 does not automatically nil weak pointers), so it is there for safety in the auto generated code. I've been wondering about this myself and that's the only reason I can come up with.

Comment: If your deployment target includes iOS 4, then you won't be able to use weak pointers anyway; they'll be `unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: Good point. Well done for actually filing a bug on this, instead of just letting it vaguely bother you like I did.

Answer (score 3):

From Documentation, the viewDidUnload

- "This method ...is your chance to perform any final cleanup. ... "
- "When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from memory"

From Documentation, about weak (Setter Semantics)

- Specifies that there is a weak (non-owning) relationship to the destination object.
  **If the destination object is deallocated,the property value is automatically set to nil**.

So it's obvious. It's consistant on the rules.**Is not about the object that your property points,but just nullify your property based on the above rule of weak.**

The viewDidUnload suppose that's your weak property can't be point to any object,
because that object is deallocated (based on the place of viewDidUnload in the life cycle of a View Controller). And simply cleans it with the nil.

It's safe for you, explicit to the weak rule and memory efficient.
The compiler can't be sure that you took the care about the pointed object.
He just need to ensure the clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Since the property is `weak`, the reference in your object won't affect the retain count of the object. So yes, there's no point in setting the object as nil. At least that's how I understand it.